# How to check if image loaded in the div the correct one

Tags: jquery

I am relatively new to jQuery and any help would be much appreciated.

What i need is a *IF statement* to check whether the image loaded in the div is the "image1.jpg" or "image2.jpg" and perform the required action depending on the return from the if statement.

Here is the code i been trying to use:

```
var image1 = $('<img />').attr('src', 'images/branding_1_thumb.jpg');   
var image1_2 = $('<img />').attr('src', 'images/branding_1_2_thumb.jpg');

if ($("#thumb2").length == image2_2.length) {
           /*action to perform*/
    }
    else {
       /*action to perform*/
}
```

I am not sure how i need to go about it. Do i need to pass the image paths as a strings and check that way?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
if($("#thumb2").attr("src") == image2_2.attr("src")) {
    // same src
}
else  {
    // not the same src
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply guys. Very fast and helpful.

This is the new code:

if($("#thumb2").attr("src") == image2_2.attr("src")) {
        $("#thumb2").hide().fadeIn(500).html(image2);
}
else  {
        $("#thumb2").html(image2);
}

What i am trying to do is to check if it returns true then fade the image2, and if not then just change it. But fading does not seem to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: hmm not sure if the problem is the fading but, #thumb2 is an <img> element and image2 is probably to I think? So you probably want `$("#thumb2").hide().fadeIn(500).attr("src", image2.attr("src"))`

Comment: Thank you again. It seems like if statement return false no matter what i put.

Comment: try some `alert()`'s to verify the value's your checking in the if statement

Comment: thank you. When i use the following statement:  alert($("#thumb2").attr("src", image2.attr("src"))); it returns [object Object], it does seem to return false as alert in the true part of statement do not show.

Comment: try `alert($("#thumb2").attr("src"))` and `alert(image2.attr("src"));`

Comment: I tried that. It only returns when in false statement and it returns 'unidentified'.

Comment: could you place your code on http://jsfiddle.net/ ? or a example of the code that doesn't work

Comment: Thank you. Here is the link in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Snvq9/ . It is a acordion. What i am trying to do is to have closed tab display one image (image2) and opened tab to display another image (image2_2) and so on. In function ($("#thumb1").click(function()) is located the if statement which i am trying to get to work and if so i can replicate across all other functions. The reason i am using if statement is to determine if tab is opened of closed, by checking what image is currently there. Then i can either apply fadeIn() or just html(). Thank you, and sorry for the wall of text.

Comment: i've minimized it to the part you describe above. Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/A4Cc6/

Comment: Cool. I think i am almost there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(image1).attr('src')=='images/branding_1_thumb.jpg') so 1 else 0
```